# How to use a static top bar in my react native expo app with a bottom nav bar as well?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I am using `react-navigation`, currently I am using the `Stack` and `Bottom Tabs`, but I also need a `Top Tabs` as well.
I see the option of `Material Top Tabs`, but again as per the rule, I can only use one navigator, any workaround to that?

Basically my top tab will have `my logo and cart icon`

and bottom tab will have usual `home, search and settings`

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution
make a custom header component and then do this

```
<Tab.Navigator
    initialRouteName="Home"
    screenOptions={{
        header: () => <Header />,
    }}
>
    <Tab.Screen
        ...

</Tab.Navigator>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a reusable `<Header />` component that has the logo and buttons in it.

Here's an example usage of a Header component that I've used for years:

```
<Header
  showLogo
  rightButton={{
     child: HorizontalDotsMenu(30, Colors.Primary),
     onclick: viewCartPressed,
  }}
/>
```

You can then place this at the top of each file that needs the `Header`.